# Create enum Z3 constant issue in C# API

Tags: c#, z3

I have an enum in C#:

```
public enum CustomerType
{
    Premium,
    Gold,
    Regular
}
```

I have created an enum sort like this:

```
var enumSort = context.MkEnumSort("CustomerType", "Premium", "Gold", "Regular");
```

How can I create the Z3 constant corresponding to `CustomerType.Premium` for instance?

Trying `context.MkConst("Premium", enumSort);` produces an enum sort that can take any CustomerType value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on Z3 C# bindings, but here's an example that can possibly help: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/dotnet/Program.cs#L1466-L1501

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this using:

`sort.As<EnumSort>().Consts.First(x => x.FuncDecl.Name.ToString() == "Premium")`.

Comment: This doesn't sound right to me as a symbolic variable wouldn't have a string component attached to it. Does it really work?

Comment: Yep, it worked in my case. I wanted to check whether the assertion: "type == CustomerType.Premium AND type == CustomerType.Gold" was unsatisfiable and it worked.